# Is it correct to write these two gerunds in succession?

Tags: gerunds, catenative-verbs

I'm speaking about this precise sentence:

> I would like to contact you because I work for a firm in which we are **considering defining** a text editor for all our Android apps:

Is there any rule to know when to use this structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is fine. *Consider* can be catenative, taking another verb or verb phrase as object. When it takes such a verb, it takes a gerund. So, "defining a text editor for all our Android apps" is a gerund phrase, and the object of *considering*, which is just a verb that is in the present progressive (not actually a gerund).

Knowing which verbs you can do this with, and what forms the verbs they take as objects should be in, is just a case of learning vocabulary through experience.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessarily wrong but there are better ways of saying this, such as, we are in the process of considering how to define a text editor.